# Display the middle elements of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently i tried learning to program and after finishing my first tutorial I am trying tackling some problems from codewars.com.

"You are going to be given a word. Your job is to return the middle character of the word. If the word's length is odd, return the middle character. If the word's length is even, return the middle 2 characters."

Here is my solution:

```
def get_middle(n):
    if len(n) % 2 == 0:
        return n[(len(n)/2) - 1] and n[(len(n)/2)]
    else:
        return n[(len(n)/2) + 0.5]
```

Unfortunately when executing the function with for example "abc" I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-24-46429b2608e5> in <module>
----> 1 print(get_middle("abc"))

<ipython-input-23-56ccbf5e17f7> in get_middle(n)
      3         return n[(len(n)/2) - 1] and n[(len(n)/2)]
      4     else:
----> 5         return n[(len(n)/2) + 1]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't understand why I always get the this kind of error. Aren't all my string indices integers? 
I know there are are a lot of different solutions out there, but I really would like to know why mine isn't working the way I intended it to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well the error is very explicit. `string indices must be integers`. You are doing `n[len(n)/2 + 0.5]` which might be a float...

Comment: when adding non-integer values to any number, it always becomes a float, e.g. `type(1 + 0.5)` is `float`. What OP wants is integer divide `//` which always rounds down to the next integer `assert 3//2 == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, there are two kinds of division: integer division and float division.

```
    print(4 / 2)
---> 2.0
    print(4 // 2)
---> 2
```

in Python 2, dividing one integer to an another integer,it comes an integer.
Since Python doesn't declare data types in advance, The interpreter automatically detects the type so you never know when you want to use integers and when you want to use a float.

Since floats lose precision, it's not advised to use them in integral calculations

To solve this problem, future Python modules included a new type of division called integer division given by the **operator //**

Now, **/ performs** - float division, and
 **// performs**  - integer division.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out by myself when trying to play around with some arithmetic operations in Python. Because 2.5 + 0.5 = 3 (in Python 3.0) I thought I already got an integer and was therefore unable to get why I didn't use an integer accordingly to the error report.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_middle(n):
if len(n) % 2 == 0:
    return n[(len(n)//2) - 1] and n[(int(len(n)/2))]
else:
    return n[int(len(n)/2+ 0.5)]
```

Comment: this does not work, since `len(n)/2` is uneven with value behind the dot being `.5`, and you want to round down, not up. But adding 0.5 rounds it up!
If you remove the `0.5` it will always round down and it will work, e.g. for input `"abc"`, `int(len(n)/2)` or `len(n)//2` becomes 1, which is the correct index.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with our code is that division casts integer to float type automatically and Python starts complaining about it. Simple solution would be to add second `/` symbol to division or in `else` case cast it to integer:

```py
def get_middle(n):
if len(n) % 2 == 0:
    return n[(len(n)//2) - 1] and n[(len(n)//2)]
else:
    return n[int((len(n)/2) + 0.5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you divide an odd integer by 2 with the `/`operator, you get a float. This float should be explicitly converted to an integer when it is used as an indice.

Comment: But that's why I tried to add 0.5! What ever odd integer I take, divided by 2 it will always be something like x.5.

Comment: Yes, but `n[1]` will work because `1` is an integer; `n[1.0]` will not work because `1.0` is a float (and `0.5 + 0.5` will give you `1.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try [math.floor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=floor#math.floor):

```py
import math                                                                     


def get_middle(value):                                                          
    length = len(value)                                                         
    if length % 2 == 0:
        # even length, pick the middle 2 characters                                                         
        start = length // 2 - 1                                                 
        end = length // 2 + 1                                                   
    else:
        # odd length, pick the middle character                                                                       
        start = math.floor(length // 2)                                         
        end = start + 1                                                         
    return value[start:end]
```

A suggestion if you are learning programming, try to break down your steps rather than doing it all in one line, it helps a lot when trying to understand the error messages.